# Safety of the Debian repository

Tags: debian, security, repository

Let's say there is an open-source application with binaries available in `.tar.xz` format, but not as a `.deb` package. And there is a `.deb` package in the Debian SW repository apparently built by the Debian community.

Given that I trust the application itself, can I also trust its version in the Debian repository? Debian team claims that they "take security very seriously". Though, how does it look in practice? Can I be sure that the security team reviews all submitted packages and verify that the code was not altered before being packed up? Or do they only react (e.g. remove package from the repo) upon an incident?

(To anticipate a question: it is beneficial to use the `.deb` package, because it simplifies update and the overall maintenance).

Comment: *"verify that the code was not altered before being packed up"* ... In the Debian maintainer's guide there's a section named "[Fix Upstream Bugs](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/modify.en.html#fixupstream)".  From this it may be inferred that maintainers do actively modify the source before distributing, maintainers are permitted to make changes.  I cannot comment on how such patches are peer reviewed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Debian Security Team does not review all packages before upload because they are a small group of volunteers and there are over 67,000 packages in the archive.  I'm not aware of any other Linux distro (or other major project or distributor) that has such a procedure, either.

However, the Debian build daemons do build every package from its source, so you can download the source package (with `apt-get source PACKAGENAME`) and verify the tarball and patches are as you expect them to be.  All source packages are cryptographically signed, as is the archive, so you can be sure that the packages have not been modified from the source that was uploaded.

Debian also has an initiative to [build all packages reproducibly](https://reproducible-builds.org/) so that you can produce a bit-for-bit identical package on your own and verify that nothing has been tampered with.  There is a [list of packages](https://tests.reproducible-builds.org/debian/unstable/amd64/index_FTBR.html) which do and don't build reproducibly.

In general, Debian is widely considered a trustworthy source of binaries and numerous major organizations use it, although of course you must make your own determination.  If you really need every binary and binary package audited, then you'll have to manage that yourself, since I'm not sure that any OS distributor of any size provides that service.

Comment: 1. Couldn't find a similar list of unreproducibly build packages for the stable release. Does it mean that only reproducibly build packages get into the stable? 2. Does it mean that all packages in Debian repo are _always_ built from sources, even if there are binaries available from application authors (see my original question). 3. Do you know if there is any published Debian policy for build reproducibility and other security requirements for packages in the repo?

Comment: 1. No, it means other than security updates and a few non-security updates, all packages are uploaded to unstable first and progress to stable.  2. All packages in `main` must build from source, even if upstream binaries are available.  `contrib` and `non-free` are encouraged but not guaranteed.  3.  There's a [SHOULD requirement](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#reproducibility).

Comment: 1. I had to better express myself. Though, [there is](https://tests.reproducible-builds.org/debian/buster/amd64/index_FTBR.html) is the same list for the stable release (under its codename).

Answer (score 3):

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq and https://warlord0blog.wordpress.com/2018/05/08/repository-not-trusted show the maintainers exercise caution.in the maintenance of their repository and have a process to alert you to potentially hazardous conditions.

I agree with you regarding the advantages of using .deb packages.

Answer (score 3):

I asked two questions with answers that describe the security-related aspects of Debian's repositories:

- [Who builds the Debian packages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367867/who-builds-the-debian-packages) (a good introduction to the packaging process)
- "Do package managers check the hashes of packages?" (duplicate) -> [**How is the authenticity of Debian packages guaranteed?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285635/how-is-the-authenticity-of-debian-packages-guaranteed) (here you can probably find the answer you're looking for)

For reproducible builds I think what it needs to make it useful in practice [before 100% of packages are reproducible](https://reproducible-builds.org/) is a convenient way to check which of *all* of the currently installed packages are not reproducible in addition to the `vrms` tool that checks for installed non-free software:
["How to list which unreproducible packages are installed on a Debian system?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590909/how-to-list-which-unreproducible-packages-are-installed-on-a-debian-system)